# search for occurrence of a string in another file in a particular column

Tags: perl, unix

I have two files:

1) Tab file with the following content. Let's call this reference file:

```
    V$HMGIY_01_rc   Ncor=0.405
V$CACD_01   Ncor=0.405
    V$GKLF_02   Ncor=0.650
    V$AML2_Q3   Ncor=0.792
    V$WT1_Q6    Ncor=0.607
V$KID3_01   Ncor=0.668
V$CNOT3_01  Ncor=0.491
    V$KROX_Q6   Ncor=0.423
V$ETF_Q6_rc Ncor=0.547
V$E2F_Q2_rc Ncor=0.653
V$SP1_Q6_01_rc  Ncor=0.650
V$SP4_Q5    Ncor=0.660
```

2) The second tab file contains the search string X as shown below. Let's call this file as search_string:

```
           A                 X
  NF-E2_SC-22827    NF-E2
  NRSF              NRSF
  NFATC1_SC-17834   NFATC1
  NFKB              NFKB
  TCF3_SC-349           TCF3
  MEF2A             MEF2A
```

what I would like to do is: Take the first search term (from search_string file; column X), check if it occurs in first column of the reference file. 
Example: The first search term is NF-E2. I would need to check if this string occurs in the first column of the reference file. If it occurs, then give a score of 1, else give 0. Also i would like to count the number of times it matches the pattern.
I want the output to be created as follows:

```
    X       X in file?  number of times it occurs
    NF-E2          1                            3
    NRSF           0                            0
    NFATC1         0                            0
    NFKB           1                            7
    TCF3           0                            0
```

Please note: I need to search each string in different files i.e. The first string (Nf-E2) should be searched in file NF-E2.tab; the second string (NRSF) should be searched in file NRSF.tab and so on. Also I would like to program it using either R or Perl scripts only.

Please help!!

Comment: Am not sure how and where to start for this?

Comment: You stated preference in using R or Perl, so you must have a reason for that, right? You've tried to solve the problem in one of those? You're probably going to get voted down because there are dozens of questions and answers here which already show you how to do that.

Comment: @veryhungrymike: I am very new to programming that is why I posted here to ask for suggestions. The reason I am particular about Perl or R is because with the output file generated from this would make job easier for further analysis.

Comment: The output is text, though, so it doesn't matter which tool you use to get it. It seemed like you already knew some R and/or Perl. [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) has given you a good start though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one-liner that you can play with and alter to suit:

```
perl -lanE '$str=$F[1];  $f="/home/$str/list/$str.txt"; $c=`grep -c "$str" "$f"`;chomp($c);$x=0;$x++ if $c;say "$str\t$x\t$c"' file2
```

It assumes your second file is called `file2`. Here is some sample output from input files I made up on my machine:

```
NF-E2   0   0
NRSF    1   1
NFATC1  1   2
TCF3    1   3
MEF2A   0   0
```

It just uses `grep -c` to count the occurrences and stores that in variable `$c`. `chomp()` removes the linefeed from the output of `grep`. `$x` is set to zero and incremented if the count (`$c`) is greater than zero. Then the result is printed using `say`.

I'll get you started with the search string and the name of the file to search in...

```
$perl -lanE '$str=$F[1];$f=$str.".txt";print "$str $f"' file2
NF-E2 NF-E2.txt
NRSF NRSF.txt
NFATC1 NFATC1.txt
NFKB NFKB.txt
TCF3 TCF3.txt
MEF2A MEF2A.txt
```

**Explanation**

Perl command-line switches used:

`-l` Perl takes care of line endings for us saving us the trouble - thanks Perl !

`-a` split the fields of the input file into an array called `$F[]`

`-n` put an implict loop around our code to process each line of the input file (file2)

`-E` execute the code that follows inside single quotes and enable the `say` feature

Then the actual code inside the single quotes (`''`)... assign the value of the second field, i.e. `$F[1]` because fields start at 0, to the variable `$str`. Assign the value of `$str` appended with ".txt" to the variable $f - which is the search string. Then print the search string `$str` and the filename `$f`.

**EDITED**

If you find Bash easier to understand, here is a Bash version.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set tabs to align output columns
tabs -12

# Output headers
echo -e "X\tPresent?\tCount"

# Extract second column of file2
awk '{print $2}' file2 | while read item
do
   # Work out name of file to search in
   FILE="/home/${item}/list/${item}.txt"

   # Count occurrences of $item in $FILE
   COUNT=$(grep -cw "$item" "$FILE")

   # If COUNT>0 the value is present
   PRESENT=0
   [ $COUNT -gt 0 ] && PRESENT=1

   echo -e "$item\t$PRESENT\t$COUNT"
done
```

Save the file as `go`, then run like this:

```
chmod +x go    # Only necessary for the first run
./go
```

Comment: With pleasure, but after lunch!

Comment: Ha ha. Sure! Guten appetit!

Comment: Tja, vielen dank. Ich habe meine Antwort upgedated!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, I still didn#t understand one thing: in the first code, where do we provide/call the first file?

Comment: Also, do we need to execute the second code first and then do the other?

Comment: The filename is the very last thing on the line - I assumed your second file is called "file2".

Comment: You don't need the second code at all - the first one does everything you need.

Comment: thank you! I will work on it now if I get any questions I will get back to you!! Thank you again!!!

Comment: Sorry for the trouble again! Do we need to have all the files we need to search in a single folder? I am asking about the NF-E2.txt, NRSF.txt etc., if they should be in a single folder? Also while executing this one-liner I assume we need to navigate the command prompt to the folder in which all files are present?

Comment: I can probably change the script to allow you to put the files somewhere else - please say how/where you want/have the files and I'll try and change it. I can also make the script go to some folder and start processing there if you tell me where it is supposed to go - or you could pass a parameter saying where to go if you prefer that - then you would run `scriptname foldername` and it would go to that folder and get working. You can Email me if you prefer - click my profile and you'll see my Email address.

Comment: Thank you for the help again! I was quite confused with the script because I was not sure where it takes the  NF-E2.txt, NRSF.txt etc., file in the script. So I am asking as a question if we need to have everything in the same folder?

Comment: Currently, the script looks in the folder where you start it for all the NF-E2.txt files. If you want it differently, please just say and I'll show you how.

Comment: I have added a Bash version that you might find easier to understand and modify... see my answer above after the word "EDITED".

Comment: I have just one problem here. It perl code (one-liner) works fine when all the files are in the same folder. the problem here is that: I have  got the files stored in subdirectories. Is there are a way to rectify this?

Comment: I already asked you that - see 7-8 questions ago! Please tell me how your files are stored and I will change it for you.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. My files are stored as follows: The files are stored as follows:
home/NF-E2/list/NF-E2.txt
home/NRSF/list/NRSF.txt
and so on..

Comment: I have updated the Perl and the Bash version for you.

Comment: I get the following error message:
grep: /12/NF-E2/list/NF-E2.tab: No such file or directory

Comment: In addition to the task above, I need to add the value that is highest among those counted. For example say if the word "Apple" is found 20 times in my file, i want to print the highest rate in my output. Input file: apple 1 20 output: apple 1 20 $8 (i.e. $8 is the highest rate found among the 20 times it occurs).